# ShinyDashboard - Error after stopping shinyApps

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio, shinydashboard

I'm building up a shinyDashboard.
Untill yesterday there wasn't any problem, but today every time I stop the app (that works perfectly) this message appears:

```
Called from: Sys.sleep(0.001)
```

I run the app by clicking on the "Run App" button in RStudio, ([here's a picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PniHP.png)) and the error message appears even if I change the "Run" options ("Run in window", "Run in external",...).

The most wierd thing is that sometimes this message doesn't appear, but it's shown ONE of these, even if don't change anything in my code:

```
Called from: ifelse(interactive(), 100, 1000)

Called from: takeElapsed()

Called from: as.numeric(Sys.time())

Called from: match(x, table, nomatch = 0L)
```

Can any one tell me what these messages are due to? I don't have any idea about it and I haven't found anything on the web.

I'm running on Windows 7 Enterprise (Service Pack 1):

- R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14) -- "Fire Safety"
- RStudio Version 0.99.891.

Comment: Would you considering upgrading your R version? It seems like your problem may be related to [this discussion](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/869).

Comment: Thanks Knorad, I've just updated R to the R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10) -- "Wooden Christmas-Tree", but the problem still exists: after I stopped the app, the message `Called from: takeElapsed()` appeared.